# Is there anyway to change the structure of the content page on Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I want to change how my content is displayed on my "add content" page. Instead of just listing the content with no particular structure other than filtering by "Content Type", "Author", "Status", etc. I want to display the content hierarchy. Like:

```
--Content1

------Content2

----------Content3

----------Content4

------Content5
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty vague question so I'm just going to suggest a few things that I think you could use:

Field Group module: Provides the ability to group your fields on both form and display.
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group

Paragraphs module: Paragraphs is the new way of content creation!
It allows you — Site Builders — to make things cleaner so that you can give more editing power to your end-users.
https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

You can also just re-arrange the order of fields in the 'manage display' tab of your content type.